# Split a sequence in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split multiple columns with sequence into different rows.

```
For example: Number Age   Sequence     Loop 
             1      12     AB           ((

Expected output: Number  Age Sequence   Loop
                  1      12   A          (
                  1      12   B           (
```

Comment: can you explain it? what is the exact pettern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the rest of your data is, but considering the provided information here is something that works ..

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   Number  Age Sequence Loop
0       1   12       AB   ((

In [2]: df['Sequence'] = df.Sequence.apply(list)
In [3]: df['Loop'] = df.Loop.apply(list)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   Number  Age Sequence    Loop
0       1   12   [A, B]  [(, (]

In [5]: df.explode('Sequence').explode('Loop').drop_duplicates()
Out[5]:
   Number  Age Sequence Loop
0       1   12        A    (
0       1   12        B    (
```

EDIT: Changing `lambda` to `list` to use with apply(). Thanks to @Timus

Comment: this will provide wrong result when loop isnt ((....

Comment: I agree is not the best solution, but based on the provided input - it does what it's expected..

Comment: Given the limited amount of information provided, this is a reasonable answer. (You don't need the `lambda` functions for `apply` here: Just `.apply(list)` is enough (`list` is callable).)

Comment: I actually knew that ... but for some reason it didn't come to my mind. Thanks :-)